# How to add custom fields in ZFC-user module for zend 2 without doctrine?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db-table, zfcuser

I have tried using creating a different module and attaching the `ZfcUser\Form\Register` over `init` method. But it wasn't working.
I want to add few custom fields, with changing any thing in the vendor dir, as is it not a good practice. I also tried using `user_entity_class` ,creating a custom 'User' class, but it was creating some route issue in other modules, with zfc-user , I'm also using `zfc-admin` and `zfc-adminuser`, the error was coming in `zfc-adminuser`, `Couldn't found the class` was the error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some issue regarding the overriding of the module ZFC-User, But still you can overwrite it manually.
One way I have used is a bit old fashioned but working. What I have done is I have copied complete module the to `module folder`. Then pointing the form towards to my module where the changes are required, rest all are pointed to default.With this you can update your module. Make sure you point the `user_entity_class` to your module something like this:

> 'user_entity_class' => 'MyZfcUser\Entity\User',

you can find this in `config\autoload\zfcuser.global.php`